# Python calling function inside other function not working

Tags: python, function, python-3.x

This is what I have right now:

```
def open_file():
    file_name = input("What is the name of the file you want to open?")
    while True:
        try:
            file = open(file_name, 'r')
            header = file.readline()
            return (file)
            break
        except FileNotFoundError:
            file_name = input("What is the name of the file you want to open?")

def process_file():
    file = open_file()
    print(file)

def main():
    process_file()
```

I can't even get it to get to prompting me for the file name I want to open. Doesn't that mean it's not a problem with my loop but the way I am calling my functions?

Comment: Unlike C, `main()` isn't called automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call `main()` to run your code. If you do that it works just fine.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you called your module something like foo.py

You could add this bit of code:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

And then in the console run:

```
  >>python foo.py
```

For an explanation of why this works, you can see this answer: [What does if __name__ == "__main__": do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do)

Answer (score 1):

You need to call `main()` in order for your code to run.

Comment: raw_input doesn't exist in Python 3